# how to use blurhash encode in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Using flutter there is a package called `blurhash_dart`. using this package to encode an image I used the following code in my statefull widget.

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context){
final fileData = File(imageGet()).readAsBytesSync();
final image = decodeImage(fileData.toList());
final blurHash = BlurHash.encode(image!, numCompX: 4, numCompY: 3);
}
```

this code is from https://pub.dev/packages/blurhash_dart. but on run this error is thrown.

```
 Cannot open file, path = 'assets/daytime/midday.jpg' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
```

what am I missing or doing causing this? thanks in advance.

file of the `pubspec.yaml`

```
assets:
- assets/images/
- assets/daytime/afternoon.jpg
- assets/daytime/dawn.jpg
- assets/daytime/dusk.jpg
- assets/daytime/evening.jpg
- assets/daytime/midday.jpg
- assets/daytime/midnight.jpg
- assets/daytime/morning.jpg
```

Comment: try removing `assets` from path and make sure adding on `pubspec.yaml` then rebuild the app.

Comment: do i have to add every images path assets/time/img1.jpg or i can just assets/time/

Comment: Simply put `assets/` on `pubspec.yaml` , and use path like `daytime/midday.jpg` and can you update the question including `pubspec.yaml` to show image imports?

Comment: I included `pubspec.yaml`. and i created the directory of my assets as `"app_name"/assets/daytime/midday.jpg`. so doesn't removing the `assets/` affect that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: when an app starts, images won't load quickly, so I'm using a `blurhash_dart` package to show a hash image. and my problem is am not familiar with this as I'm new to flutter. I already included assets in `pubspec.yaml` and it loads fine, but when I try to use it in  `File(imageGet()).readAsBytesSync();` it throws the above error.